# How to keep Facebook chat online in Google Chrome with facebook tab closed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, facebook, facebook-messenger

I was just trying to stay in touch with Facebook without keep the Facebook tab always open.

Now I can check any notification with [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmameahlembdcigphohgiodcgjomcgeo) Google Chrome extension

And I have to open the tab only when something arrive.

The next step is to keep the chat online without the tab opened. I tried find some extension but none I found can do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to have a facebook chat only tab

http://www.facebook.com/presence/popout.php

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rockmelt browser](http://www.rockmelt.com) - which is based on Chrome, and included a standalone Facebook chat client on the 'edges' of the browser screen. It also allows you to see notifications, updates etc without having to visit the Facebook website.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [trillian](http://www.trillian.im/). Its a free program that allows you to link to your instant messaging/social network sites. I just started using it and I find it to be pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, you can use [Adium](http://adium.im/). Or you could use [this](http://www.chromeextensions.org/social-communications/facebook-chat/) Chrome extension.